# Download file parts via FTP using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ftp, download

I need my program to download large files via FTP by specifying FTP username and password.
Also it must have "Pause" function, that's why I need my program to get file parts.
I use VB.NET and .NET 3.5 Framework. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You need to use some third-party FTP/FTPS client component for .NET for this. I can mention Rebex.NET and our SecureBlackbox and there are others available.

Comment: I know Rebex, but I think it's possible without Rebex. I've found that it's possible with System.Net.FtpWebRequest . But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Download WinSCP from NuGet Package

```
Import WinSCP <br>
Public Class fmbFtp <br>

    Private Sub btnDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click

        Try

            ' Setup session options

            Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions

            With sessionOptions
                .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
                .HostName = "example.com"
                .UserName = "UserName"
                .Password = "Password"
                'telnet command to get key
                'ssh-keygen - l - f / etc / ssh / ssh_host_rsa_key
                .SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"

            End With

            Using session As New Session

                ' Connect

                session.Open(sessionOptions)

                ' Upload files

                Dim transferOptions As New TransferOptions
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary

                Dim transferResult As TransferOperationResult
                transferResult = session.GetFiles("/path/filename.txt", My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory)
                ' Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check()
                ' Print results
                For Each transfer In transferResult.Transfers
                    Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName)
                Next
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FtpWebRequest like this :

```
Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest =   DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("FTP Path along with destination file name"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")

Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("path of file to be copied")

Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
strz.Close()
strz.Dispose()
```

This works for me.

Comment: I think you've written this code for uploading to server, not for downloading. You've used System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UPLOADFILE method.